# When using MSBuild to build a WPF project which files should I specify for compilation? does order matter?

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild

I'm attempting to automate the build process of my WPF project and set up a CI system. I'm following details found in *Continuous Integration in .NET* by Marcin Kawalerowicz and Craig Bernston. Specifically, details in chapter 3 pertaining to build automation in MSBuild. The authors provide a sample build file for a project consisting of a single C# file, which looks similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build;Deploy;Execute" 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Debug Condition="'$(Delete)'==''">false</Debug>
    <OutputFile>SampleMSBuild.exe</OutputFile>
    <OutputDirectory>Output</OutputDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    **<CompileFile Include="SampleMSBuild.cs" />**
    <DeleteFiles Include="SampleMSBuild.exe;SampleMSBuild.pdb" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    ...
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTarget="Clean">
    **<Csc Sources="@(CompileFiles)"**
         OutputAssembly="$(OutputFile)"
         EmitDebugInformation="$(Debug)" />
  <Target Name="Deploy">
    ...
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Execute">
    ...
  </Target>
</Project>
```

My confusion arises from the two lines of code I've surrounded in asterisks. Although I now know how to build a project with a single source file, I am unsure how to scale that up to a WPF project where there is a predefined template with many source files that are placed in different directories. Is it simply a matter of including every source file in the project like so

```
... 
<CompileFile Include="source1.cs;source2.cs;source3.cs;...;sourceN.cs"
...
```

What about files in a project that are NOT source code? For example, files found in the References folder of a WPF project. I can't imagine all these are to be compiled as well. Does the complied source code communicate with the rest of the uncompiled files in the project? What exactly is the relationship between source files and other non-source files when it comes to build automation in MSBuild?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the csproj file to msbuild?

Comment: What Klaus said: starting from a csproj generated by e.g. Visual Studio is more interesting, it works for CI just as well. If you need to include many files use wildcards like `<CompileFile Include="**\*.cs" />` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-select-the-files-to-build?view=vs-2019